# ajax post insertion by php fails

Tags: ajax

```
Here is my code..i am trying to make an ajax application..this is my insertion code..when i send requests to this from my client side java script page, insertion is made to the data base by this php code avording to the reuest sent from the client side java script..when i insert by static array for testing insertion works fine..but when ever i send dynamic dynamic $_POST array from client side javascript it show mysql syntax error..Please if some one can help..
```

O ..here is my edited segment..it is much more compact ..but the same problem..it show mysql syntax error.. on line 1.. I dont know when staticaly tested this php 
file works fine..but when run from client side javascript via ajax it shows
furstrating mysql syntax error.thanks in advance..

```
include('db_constant.php');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");


function insert_into($post_array)
{
  $conn = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,WBUT_MAIN);

    /* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
   {
    die( mysqli_connect_error());

   }
  else
   {

     $outp='';
    $college_name='';
    $college_name.= $post_array['clg_frm'].'_result';
    //echo $college_name; 
    $sgpa="";$cgpa="";$ygpa="";
    //$post_array[8]=(int)$post_array[8];
    //echo $post_array[0];
    $post_array['C_O']=(int)$post_array['C_O'];
    echo $post_array['C_O'];
    $query='INSERT INTO '.$college_name.'(wbut_reg_no,wbut_roll_no,fastname,lastname,stream,degree,semestar,suba,subano,sub2_code,sub2_no,sub3_code,sub3_no,sub4_code,sub4_no,sub5_code,sub5_no,sub6_code,sub6_no,sub7_code,sub7_no,';
    $query.='sub8_code,sub8_no,sub9_code,sub9_no,sub10_code,sub10_no,sub11_code,sub11_no,sub12_code,sub12_no,sgpa,cgpa,ygpa)'; 
    $query.='VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

    //echo $query;
    echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
    echo $conn->error;

    $stmt->bind_param('sssssisisisisisisisisisisisisisss',$post_array['reg_frm'],$post_array['roll_frm'],$post_array['fast_frm'],
    $post_array['last_frm'],$post_array['dept_frm'],$post_array['degree_frm'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],
    $post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O']
    ,$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O']
    ,$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O']
    ,$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O'],$post_array['C_O']);
    //echo $stmt->error;

    $result=$stmt->execute();


    if($result)
    $outp='[{"status":"success","id":"'.$post_array['clg_frm'].'"}]';
    else
    $outp='[{"status":"failure"}]';

    echo $outp;

   }

/* close connection */
   $conn->close();
}
$array_post=array();


 $array_post=$_POST;
 //foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    // {
      //       $array_post[$key]=$value;
             //$index_value[$i]=$value;
             //$i++; 

     //}

 // $_POST=array('reg_frm'=>'2','clg_frm'=>'george_college');

 print_r($_POST);

 insert_into($array_post);


//print_r($array_post);
?>
```